# How do I run a command when I'm facing a certain direction? [1.14]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was told to try `/execute if entity[y_rotation=85..95] run [command]`,
but this only seems to work in 1.13.

What command do I need to use when a player is facing north or west in 1.14(.3)?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `execute if entity @s[y_rotation=85..95] run [command]`. If you run this as yourself it will only run when you are facing that direction. If you do `execute as @a[y_rotation=85..95] run [command]` in a repeating command block it will execute as any player who is facing that direction.

Comment: You can change the target selectors in the `if entity` and `as entity` parts as you need for your given application.